# Passing a lambda to a virtual function

Tags: c++, lambda, virtual-functions

Typically the idiom to pass a lambda functor to a method relies on templating the argument:

```
template<typename Functor>
void apply(Functor f)
{
   f(stuff);
}
```

However, the C++ language doesn't support template arguments for virtual declarations. Hereby the problem: There is no succinct way to define a virtual interface that handles some lambda:

```
virtual void apply(Lambda???) = 0;
```

Perhaps there is one way: converting lambdas to the heavyweight `std::function` and using that

Is there another way to pass a lambda to a virtual method besides that one?

I thought perhaps bypassing the limitation by declaring the functor as a type parameter in the type class:

```
template<typename SomeArgs, typename Functor>
struct interface
{
    virtual void apply(Functor&& f) = 0;
};
```

but lambdas are not necessarily type-compatible even if they have the same signatures, so this doesn't really but me anything. Perhaps `std::function` is the only way?

Comment: Existence of `std::function` suggests that there IS a way (because after creation it doesn't care if you assign it a function pointer or lambda). But it's not an easy one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to do something equivalent to `std::function`.  The reason is that the virtual function you’re calling might be defined in some other translation unit, and so it can’t possibly adapt to whatever implicit conversions or default arguments your lambda might have.  All it can do is call a well-known virtual function itself (via `std::function<…>::operator()`) which you have defined to call your lambda.